# two intersection of affine open subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

let $ X $ be a separated scheme over an affine scheme $ S$. let $U$ and $V$ be open affine subsets of $X$.Then $U\cap V$ is also affine.and Give an example to to show that this is fails if $X$ is not separated.

This is an exercise  4.3(Chapter 2)of Hartshorne.

I know that closed subschme of an affine scheme is affine. But I don't know how to use this when $S$ is affine scheme.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The affine plane with the doubled origin has open affine sets $U$ and $V$, each isomorphic to the affine plane. But $U \cap V$ is the affine plane with a point removed, which is not affine.

Comment: How to prove it is affine?

Comment: $U$ and $V$ being affine comes from the construction of the affine plane with doubled origin.